# TCL Find in list

Tags: regex, tcl

I need to search in a list an exact word *CUT_LEVEL_EP1.5* without being able to use the elements that are before and after my string. 
 below is my list :

```
set l {L1555(CUT_LEVEL_EP1.5-1) L1560(CUT_LEVEL_EP1.5-2) L1565(CUT_LEVEL_EP1.5) L1570(CUT_LEVEL_EP1.5-3)}
```

here’s what I tried to do :

```
set index [lsearch -regexp $l {\yCUT_LEVEL_EP1.5\M}]

if {$index > -1} {
    puts [lindex $l $index]
}
```

The result is not what I expect `L1555(CUT_LEVEL_EP1.5-1)`
 I would like this `L1565(CUT_LEVEL_EP1.5)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your requirements don't match the built-in definition of a "word", you cannot use the \M constraint escape. An alternative may be to use a negative lookahead:

```
lsearch -regexp $l {\yCUT_LEVEL_EP1.5(?![A-Z0-5.-])}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you want to find the string only if it is the entirety of the contents of the parentheses. (You also want to avoid the trap of `.` matching things other than itself.) You can do it easily, but only with a little trickery.

```
set str "CUT_LEVEL_EP1.5"
set index [lsearch -regexp $l ***=($str)]
```

The `***=` says that the rest of the RE is a literal, and then we put the parentheses directly (as well as substituting in the string we are really looking for, safe because of the force-literal trick).

Comment: Thanks @Donal , but sorry if it's not clear , but I don’t want to use parentheses, it may be that in my list the parentheses are not present and If I try your code your RE `***=($str)` use this...